DMatrix/Booster has not been initialized or has already been disposed
I trained an xgboost.cox for mlr3prob and mlr3extralearner and I saved it (RDS). Then I copied it to my another system to predict new data. But error comes up:
src/c_api/c_api.cc:675: DMatrix/Booster has not been initialized or has already been disposed.
This happened PipeOp surv.xgboost.cox's $predict()
Thanks for help!!! 
I used R-4.2.3 and mlrextralearner 1.0.0 and the version of mlr3prob is 0.6.9
I add code:
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3proba)
library(mlr3verse)
library(mlr3extralearners)
library(xgboost)
library(dplyr)
lung_filter = lung |> select(-sex,-ph.ecog)
task = TaskSurv$new(id="lung",backend = lung_filter,time = "time",event = "status")
learner = lrn("surv.xgboost.cox")$train(task)
saveRDS(task,"task.rds")
saveRDS(learner,"learner.rds")
xgb.save(learner$model$model, "xgb.model")
# [1] TRUE
learner$predict_newdata(lung_filter,task)
# <PredictionSurv> for 228 observations:
#   row_ids time status    crank       lp     distr
# 1  306   TRUE 66.05680 66.05680 <list[1]>
#   2  455   TRUE 65.66539 65.66539 <list[1]>
#   3 1010  FALSE 58.95570 58.95570 <list[1]>
#   ---                                                
#   226  105  FALSE 58.55264 58.55264 <list[1]>
#   227  174  FALSE 63.55852 63.55852 <list[1]>
#   228  177  FALSE 59.69077 59.69077 <list[1]>
learner$predict(task)
# <PredictionSurv> for 228 observations:
#   row_ids time status    crank       lp     distr
# 1  306   TRUE 66.05680 66.05680 <list[1]>
#   2  455   TRUE 65.66539 65.66539 <list[1]>
#   3 1010  FALSE 58.95570 58.95570 <list[1]>
#   ---                                                
#   226  105  FALSE 58.55264 58.55264 <list[1]>
#   227  174  FALSE 63.55852 63.55852 <list[1]>
#   228  177  FALSE 59.69077 59.69077 <list[1]>

rm(list=ls())
lung_filter = lung |> select(-sex,-ph.ecog)
task2 = readRDS("task.rds")
learner2 = readRDS("learner.rds")
learner2$model$model
# ##### xgb.Booster
# Handle is invalid! Suggest using xgb.Booster.complete
# raw: 1.2 Mb 
# call:
#   xgboost::xgb.train(data = data, nrounds = 1000L, verbose = 0L, 
#                      nthread = 1L, objective = "survival:cox", eval_metric = "cox-nloglik")
# params (as set within xgb.train):
#   nthread = "1", objective = "survival:cox", eval_metric = "cox-nloglik", validate_parameters = "TRUE"
# # of features: 6 
# niter: 1000
# nfeatures : 6 
model = xgb.load("xgb.model")
model
# ##### xgb.Booster
# raw: 1.2 Mb 
# xgb.attributes:
#   niter
# niter: 999
learner2$model$model = model
learner2$model$model
# ##### xgb.Booster
# raw: 1.2 Mb 
# xgb.attributes:
#   niter
# niter: 999
learner2$predict_newdata(lung_filter,task2)
# Error in predict.xgb.Booster(model, newdata = train_data, , objective = "survival:cox") : 
#   [09:40:13] src/c_api/c_api.cc:916: DMatrix has not been initialized or has already been disposed.
learner2$predict(task2)
# Error in predict.xgb.Booster(model, newdata = train_data, , objective = "survival:cox") : 
#   [09:41:20] src/c_api/c_api.cc:916: DMatrix has not been initialized or has already been disposed.

Packages version is
[1] dplyr_1.1.4             xgboost_1.7.7.1         mlr3proba_0.6.9         mlr3verse_0.3.0         mlr3tuning_1.0.0        paradox_1.0.1
[7] survival_3.7-0          mlr3extralearners_1.0.0 mlr3_0.22.1

Can you post a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Yes, I have added code for this problem

Thanks -- where does lung come from?

For future reference, this was answered in an mlr3extralearners issue
